# Numbering ListView

Tags: delphi, listview, enumeration, lazarus

How can I numbering items in ListView (vsReport)? Now I have something like that:

```
Item := ListView1.Items.Add;
Item.Caption :=inttostr(Item.Index+1);
```

but it only works if items are not sorted. If I sort everything is mixed.

Answer (score 6):

Whenever the list is sorted you need to loop through the items and update the caption.

```
for i := 0 to ListView1.Items.Count-1 do
  ListView1.Items[i].Caption := IntToStr(i+1);
```

Personally I would switch to using the list view in virtual mode which makes adding an index column trivial. As you have it at present you need to work hard to keep the list's contents in sync with the underlying data. With a virtual list view that problem dissolves.

Comment: +1 for switching to virtual mode. Sorted items are easier to work with when you manage them outside of the ListView.

Answer (score 3):

Try moving the logic of numbering to a procedure, and call this method after of sort the listview.

try this sample

```
procedure SetNumbering(ListView : TListView);
var
 i : integer;
begin
 ListView.Items.BeginUpdate;
 try
   for i := 0 to ListView.Items.Count-1 do
     ListView.Items.Item[i].Caption:=IntToStr(i+1);
 finally
  ListView.Items.EndUpdate;
 end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is one problem. If sorted items have the same value order is wrong, for example: 1 2 3 5 4 - (4 and 5 have the same value)

Comment: How you are sorting the TListView?

Comment: If you are numbering the listview using the caption property , you must pick another column to sort the listview. Also when you insert new items in the listview call BeginUpdate, EndUpdate , then sort the listview and finally call SetNumbering.

Comment: much better to use virtual list view!

Answer (score 0):

I would take an approach more like doing some custom drawing. About 1/4 of the time I ever use list controls, I wind up using its custom drawing capabilities to accommodate for things like this. Refer to [This Article](http://www.delphidabbler.com/articles?article=16) which goes into some detail on how to accomplish custom drawing. You can check the index of the item as it's being drawn, and draw your number to the left of each item. I can put together a sample if you would like, but it is quite a bit of coding to do. But not only do you accomplish the numbering you want, but you can also do many other things like implement your own styles, draw images, draw other controls, etc.